OIDC (Open ID Connect) integration with Jaspersoft server
I am not a Java developer.
I have a Jasperreports server community edition (8..). I would like to integrate SSO here using OpenID (Microsoft Entra ID). I saw videos like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qb_2_iiwhmw  ; but in that video they are using a lot of custom code and libraries related to OpenId. And those are not available in any public domain.
Can anyone help here on how to integrate OIDC with JasperSoft Server?
Thank you
